# when passing extra key value pair in multipartformdata that is not in modelserializer, how do to get value in validated_data after running .is_valid()

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

this is the test i am running

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_product_creation(product_stack, client):
    user, token, category, subcategory, supplier, _ = product_stack
    subsubcategory = SubSubcategory.objects.create(title="smartphone", slug="smartphone", subcategory=subcategory)
    subsubcategoryattribute_color = SubSubcategoryAttribute.objects.create(attribute="color", sub_subcategory=subsubcategory)
    subsubcategoryattribute_processor = SubSubcategoryAttribute.objects.create(attribute="processor", sub_subcategory=subsubcategory)

    product_images = []
    for i in range(1, 5):
        image_file = open(f"tests/images/product-image-{i}.webp", "rb")
        image = SimpleUploadedFile(f"product-image-{i}.webp", image_file.read(), content_type="image/webp")
        product_images.append(image) 
    payload = {
        "id": user.id,
        "product_name": "Test Product",
        "description": "Test Product Description",
        "category": category.id,
        "sub_category": subcategory.id,
        "supplier": supplier.id,
        "image": product_images[0],
        "image2": product_images[1],
        "image3": product_images[2],
        "image4": product_images[3],
        "price": 1000,
        "slug": "test-product",
        "brand": "Test Brand",
        "minimum_order_quantity": 1,
        "clicks": 69,
        "max_price": 10000,
        "min_price": 1000,
        "variants": [
            {
                "variant_type": "color",
                "price": 1234,
                "available": True,
                "image": product_images[0],
                "attributes": {
                    subsubcategoryattribute_color.id: "red",
                    subsubcategoryattribute_processor.id: "snapdragon 865",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    response = client.post(reverse("submit_product_api"), payload, format="multipart", **token)
    print(response.data)
    assert response.status_code == 201
```

the variants is not in model so i also created a field to be validated in serializer

```
class NewProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    variants = VariantsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ["product_name", "description", "category", "sub_category", "price", "max_price",
                  "minimum_order_quantity", "image", "image2", "image3", "image4", "variants"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        new_slug = slugify(validated_data['product_name'])
        supplier = self.context['supplier']

        new_product = Products.objects.create(
            product_name=validated_data['product_name'],
            slug=new_slug,
            description=validated_data['description'],
            category=validated_data['category'],
            sub_category=validated_data.get('sub_category'),
            price=validated_data['price'],
            max_price=validated_data.get('max_price'),
            supplier=supplier,
            minimum_order_quantity=validated_data['minimum_order_quantity'],
            image=validated_data.get('image'),
            image2=validated_data.get('image2'),
            image3=validated_data.get('image3'),
            image4=validated_data.get('image4')
        )
        variants = validated_data.pop('variants')
        for variant in variants:
            variant["product"] = new_product
            attribute = variant.pop("attributes")
            new_variant = ProductVariant.objects.create(**variant)
            attribute_list = []
            for att, val in attribute.items():
                data = {"variant": new_variant, "attribute": SubSubcategoryAttribute.objects.get(id=att), "value": val}
                attribute_list.append(VariantAttributes(**data))
            VariantAttributes.objects.bulk_create(attribute_list)

        return new_product
```

and its corresponding serializer for serializing the variants

```
class NewProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    variants = VariantsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ["product_name", "description", "category", "sub_category", "price", "max_price",
                  "minimum_order_quantity", "image", "image2", "image3", "image4", "variants"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        new_slug = slugify(validated_data['product_name'])
        supplier = self.context['supplier']

        new_product = Products.objects.create(
            product_name=validated_data['product_name'],
            slug=new_slug,
            description=validated_data['description'],
            category=validated_data['category'],
            sub_category=validated_data.get('sub_category'),
            price=validated_data['price'],
            max_price=validated_data.get('max_price'),
            supplier=supplier,
            minimum_order_quantity=validated_data['minimum_order_quantity'],
            image=validated_data.get('image'),
            image2=validated_data.get('image2'),
            image3=validated_data.get('image3'),
            image4=validated_data.get('image4')
        )
        variants = validated_data.pop('variants')
        for variant in variants:
            variant["product"] = new_product
            attribute = variant.pop("attributes")
            new_variant = ProductVariant.objects.create(**variant)
            attribute_list = []
            for att, val in attribute.items():
                data = {"variant": new_variant, "attribute": SubSubcategoryAttribute.objects.get(id=att), "value": val}
                attribute_list.append(VariantAttributes(**data))
            VariantAttributes.objects.bulk_create(attribute_list)

        return new_product
```

and finally here is the views i am working with

```
class SubmitProductAPIView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTSupplierAuthentication]

    def post(self, request):
        user = get_pop_user_from_request(request.data)
        if user is None:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials')

        if not user.supplier.verified:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("Not a verified supplier")

        context = {
            "supplier": user.supplier
        }
        new_product = NewProductSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
        if new_product.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_product.save()
            return Response(new_product.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(new_product.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

what i am expecting is to pop the variants after it is validated by NewProductSerializer and loop through variants and save it all the details is in the create method of NewProductSerializer